# Switch Mongodb auth

Tags: mongodb, docker

Im trying to switch a mongodb with no auth to one with it, by following the below guide:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Im testing against a docker image as that seemed a nice easy option but at the moment, when i do the restart of the service its not forcing it to user --auth to login!

Steps to re-create:

1: docker run --name my-mongo -p 27017:27017 -d mongo
2: docker exec -it my-mongo (opens mongo shell)
3: (run create user code)
4: restart container
5: docker exec -it my-mongo mongod --auth --port 27017 (returns the below output)

[image]

The whole options security auth enabled! seemed like good news to me!.  But i can still do a

```
mongo --port 27017
```

and connect to the box.. which it seems to suggest i shouldnt

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error means you already have a mongod running at 27017, which is not a surprise: At step 1, you spin up a mongod instance and when you restart the container that instance is back, so at step 5, creating another mongod will cause a port conflict.

They are more convenient ways to enable auth with docker.

`docker run -d --name some-mongo -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongoadmin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret mongo`

If you need more user, use this as your Dockerfile

```
FROM mongo:4
COPY setup.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

and in `setup.sh` put something like

```
mongo=( mongo --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 --quiet )
mongo+=(
    --username="$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME"
    --password="$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD"
    --authenticationDatabase="$rootAuthDatabase"
)
export MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE="${MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE:-testdb}"
export MONGO_APP_USER=${MONGO_APP_USER:-usr}
export MONGO_APP_USER_PWD=${MONGO_APP_USER_PWD:-pwd}
export MONGO_DB_OWNER=${MONGO_DB_OWNER:-dbowner}
export MONGO_DB_OWNER_PWD=${MONGO_DB_OWNER_PWD:-pwd}

"${mongo[@]}" "$MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE" <<-EOJS
    db.createUser({
        user: $(jq --arg 'user' "$MONGO_APP_USER" --null-input '$user'),
        pwd: $(jq --arg 'pwd' "$MONGO_APP_USER_PWD" --null-input '$pwd'),
        roles: [ { role: 'readWrite', db: $(jq --arg 'db' "$MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE" --null-input '$db') } ]
    });
    db.createUser({
        user: $(jq --arg 'user' "$MONGO_DB_OWNER" --null-input '$user'),
        pwd: $(jq --arg 'pwd' "$MONGO_DB_OWNER_PWD" --null-input '$pwd'),
        roles: [ { role: 'dbOwner', db: $(jq --arg 'db' "$MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE" --null-input '$db') } ]
    })
EOJS
```

Comment: Hi Siyu,  Thanks, yes i know i can start a docker image with the password set, im doing it to practise as we have a work cluster that doesnt have it set, so wanted to try and get it working on a dev machine first. Cheers.